# angular cannot get data from other component

Tags: angular

i'm using a service to get data from another component. This is working fine but if i'm trying to do the following i get an error:

```
      <span>{{dataset.name}}</span>
```

Here is my constructor (the log ist working fine)

```
  this.clientService.observable.subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data.name);
  this.dataset = data;
});
```

Here is the error what i get:

> core.js:5828 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Here is my Service:

```
export class ClientService {
 locationsObject: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
 observable: Observable<any> = this.locationsObject.asObservable();

 constructor() { }
}
```

and here is how i set the data:

```
    this.clientService.locationsObject.next(location);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dataset` variable isn't defined (because it's assigned asynchronously) when the expression is trying to access the `name` property. You could use the [safe navigation operator `?.`](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths) to check if the variable is defined before trying to access it's properties. Try the following

```html
<span>{{ dataset?.name }}</span>
```

Or you could check using `*ngIf` directive if the `dataset` variable is defined before trying to access it's properties.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="dataset">
  <span>{{ dataset.name }}</span>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: but then i dont get the data so its always ""

Comment: It should be rendered in the template when the next value is emitted to the `locationsObject` Subject. If you wish to assign the current value held by the `locationsObject` observable as soon as you subscribe to it, you could look into RxJS `BehaviorSubject` instead of `Subject`. In that case the definition would be  `locationsObject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);`